# After PHP Routing my Js file window.location.href is not working

Tags: javascript, php, redirect, routes, url-routing

I have a question After using PHP URL Routing my main.js file `window.location.href` is not working every error message shows in console but redirect is not working how can solve it?
here are my codes

Routing.php

```
$request = $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'];
$router= str_replace('/','',$request);

// ROUTING FOR INDEX PAGE
if($router=='/' || $router=='/index'){
    include('index.php');
}
// ROUTING FOR LOGIN PAGE
elseif($router=='/login'){
    include('login.php');
}
```

JS CODE

```
function login_btn(){
    jQuery('.input_error').html('');
    var email=jQuery("#login_email").val();
    var password=jQuery("#login_password").val();
    var login_error='';

    if(email==''){
        jQuery('#login_email_error').html('Please enter your Email Address');
        login_error='yes';
    }
    if(password==''){
        jQuery('#login_password_error').html('Please enter Password');
        login_error='yes';
    }
    if(login_error==''){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url:'login_process.php',
            type:'post',
            data:'email='+email+'&password='+password,
            success:function(result){
                if(result=='login_failed'){
                    jQuery('#login_message').html('<p class="alert alert-danger">Incorrect Email Address or Password</p>');
                }
                if(result=='success'){
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

All errors are working but result is showing in console